# How to shift rows in python pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, shift

I have a dataframe in which I need to copy all 10 rows 50th times below this ten rows after dropping first row and adding new row with DFM value 100% at last in every iteration. Like below example.

df1:-

```
    Cal     Group       DFM
     1     period 1    39.36%
     2     period 1    98.89
     3     period 1    99.95%
     4     period 1    99.97%
     5     period 1    99.99%
     6     period 1    100.00%
     7     period 1    100.00%
     8     period 1    100.00%
     9     period 1    100.00%
    10    period 1    100.00%
```

Result:- I have printed it 3 times and shifted values 3 times. But I need do this 50 times again and again.

```
    Cal     Group       DFM
     1     period 1    39.36%
     2     period 1    98.89
     3     period 1    99.95%
     4     period 1    99.97%
     5     period 1    99.99%
     6     period 1    100.00%
     7     period 1    100.00%
     8     period 1    100.00%
     9     period 1    100.00%
    10    period 1    100.00%
     1      period 1    98.89
     2     period 1    99.95%
     3     period 1    99.97%
     4     period 1    99.99%
     5     period 1    100.00%
     6     period 1    100.00%
     7     period 1    100.00%
     8     period 1    100.00%
     9     period 1    100.00%
    10    period 1    100.00%
     1     period 1    99.95%
     2     period 1    99.97%
     3     period 1    99.99%
     4     period 1    100.00%
     5     period 1    100.00%
     6     period 1    100.00%
     7     period 1    100.00%
     8    period 1    100.00%
     9    period 1    100.00%
    10    period 1    100.00%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension with `shift`ed versions of the dataframe and then `concat`anate them together. To keep `Cal` and `Group` aside from computations, we set them as the index first. Also, since shifting will induce missing values in `DFM`, we pass the desired fill value i.e., `"100.00%"` to `shift`. Lastly, we reset the index to get `Cal` and `Group` as columns again:

```
df_with_new_idx = df.set_index(["Cal", "Group"])

repeat = 50
new_df = pd.concat([df_with_new_idx.shift(-j, fill_value="100.00%")
                    for j in range(repeat)])

new_df = new_df.reset_index()
```

For repeating 3 times instead of 50 above for illustration, I get:

```
>>> new_df

    Cal     Group      DFM
0     1  period 1   39.36%
1     2  period 1    98.89
2     3  period 1   99.95%
3     4  period 1   99.97%
4     5  period 1   99.99%
5     6  period 1  100.00%
6     7  period 1  100.00%
7     8  period 1  100.00%
8     9  period 1  100.00%
9    10  period 1  100.00%
10    1  period 1    98.89
11    2  period 1   99.95%
12    3  period 1   99.97%
13    4  period 1   99.99%
14    5  period 1  100.00%
15    6  period 1  100.00%
16    7  period 1  100.00%
17    8  period 1  100.00%
18    9  period 1  100.00%
19   10  period 1  100.00%
20    1  period 1   99.95%
21    2  period 1   99.97%
22    3  period 1   99.99%
23    4  period 1  100.00%
24    5  period 1  100.00%
25    6  period 1  100.00%
26    7  period 1  100.00%
27    8  period 1  100.00%
28    9  period 1  100.00%
29   10  period 1  100.00%
```

Comment: I need your help on this https://stackoverflow.com/q/68241266/16292010

Comment: looks like you have an answer