# How to get index number of rows with condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, indexing

I have one dataframe in which I need to do comparison with Date column with conditions and need to get index numbers.

**Condition:-**

1. If date == 01-06-2018 then get me index number of all rows that contains that date.
2. else compare it with that date which is exact before 01-06-2018 and that date is 01-12-2017 in this dataframe.

So now how can we get the index number of all rows that contains 01-12-2017 date using second condition.

Dataframe:-

```
 SR.No     Date
  1      01-12-2013
  1      01-12-2014
  1      01-12-2015
  1      01-12-2016
  1      01-12-2017 
  1      01-12-2018
  1      01-12-2019
  1      01-12-2020 
  1      01-12-2013
  1      01-12-2014
  1      01-12-2015
  1      01-12-2016
  1      01-12-2017 
  1      01-12-2018
  1      01-12-2019
  1      01-12-2020 
  2      01-12-2013
  2      01-12-2014
  2      01-12-2015
  2      01-12-2016
  2      01-12-2017
  2      01-12-2018
  2      01-12-2019 
  2      01-12-2020 
  2      01-12-2013
  2      01-12-2014
  2      01-12-2015
  2      01-12-2016
  2      01-12-2017
  2      01-12-2018
  2      01-12-2019 
  2      01-12-2020
```

Comment: btw what is your date format?`dd-mm-yy` or `mm-dd-yy`?

Comment: Date format is dd-mm-yy.

Comment: gotcha....updated answer kindly have a look ***:)***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom function:

```
def getdate(date,df=df):
    df=df.copy()
    df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True)
    date=pd.to_datetime(date,dayfirst=True)
    if df['Date'].eq(date).any():
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
    else:
        date=(date-pd.DateOffset(months=6))
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
```

Finally:

```
out=getdate('01-06-2018')
```

output of `out`:

```
Int64Index([4, 12, 20, 28], dtype='int64')
```

**Explaination:**

we are creating a function which check the given date (currently '01-06-2018' is given) is equal to the dates in `df['Date']` Series and it returns boolean Series and we are passing that boolean series into DataFrame `df` and filtering the results and getting index by using `.index` attribute this is happening in `if` block and In the `else` block if there is no row present in the dataframe for the condition that we checked in `if` block then we are substracting or you can also say rounding the date to 6 month previous(by using `pd.DateOffset()`) so now the date(that you entered (currently '01-06-2018' is given) becomes '01-12-2017'(since we are using `to_datetime()` method inside the function so it becomes '2017-12-01') so then we are checking if this date is present in the 'df3' column in your dataframe if it is present then it will give you the indexes else it will give you empty Series

**Explaination of every line inside the function:**

```
def getdate(date,df=df):
    df=df.copy()
    #creating the copy of the dataframe so that the changes made here doesn't reflect in your original dataframe
    df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True)
    #converting the Date column to datetime dtype
    date=pd.to_datetime(date,dayfirst=True)
    #converting the date that you passed when calling the function '01-06-2018' to datetime
    if df['Date'].eq(date).any():
    #checking if '01-06-2018' is present in 'Date' column
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
        #Filtering out result and getting index
    else:
    #If '01-06-2018' is not present in 'Date' column then
        date=(date-pd.DateOffset(months=6))
        #Rounding/substracting the 6 months so now date become '2017-12-01'
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
        #Filtering out result and getting index
```

### Update:

After adding conditions your function becomes:

```
def getdate(date,df=df):
    df=df.copy()
    df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],dayfirst=True)
    date=pd.to_datetime(date,dayfirst=True)
    if df['Date'].eq(date).any():
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
    else:
        to_check=pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['01-03-18','01-06-2018','01-09-2018']),dayfirst=True)
        if to_check.isin([date]).any():
            date=pd.to_datetime('01-12-2017',dayfirst=True)
        else:
            date=(date-pd.DateOffset(months=6))
        return df[df['Date'].eq(date)].index
```

Comment: The date formats is dd-mm-yyyy. Did you try on this format. And can you please explain this else part. Actually this function is new to me. Thanks!!

Comment: @Yaser updated answer....kindly have a look ***:)***

Comment: Thanks it was a great explaination :) but if we have 01-03-2018 or 01-09-2018 instead of 01-06-2018 then will it work for these dates as well?

Comment: @Yaser yup it will work for any date with the same condition if the provided date is present in the dataframe then it will give the index and if it is not present then it will round the date to 6 month previous and check for that date and if it will not able to find that date as well then it will return empty Series

Comment: I got everything but just need to know that as you said earlier that "we are rounding the date to 6 month previous so so now the date(that you entered (currently '01-06-2018' is given) becomes '01-12-2017'."  But if we enter 01-03-2018 or 01-09-2018 then will it become 01-12-2017.

Comment: And last thing what is "date-pd" in date=(date-pd.DateOffset(months=6))? Thanks:)

Comment: @Yaser If we enter `01-03-2018` then it becomes `2017-09-01` and if we enter `01-09-2018` then it becomes `2018-03-01` you can manually check this by: `pd.to_datetime('01-09-2018',dayfirst=True)-pd.DateOffset(months=6)`

Comment: @Yaser `pd` is `pandas` module coz i have imported as `import pandas as pd` `DateOffest()` is a method in `pands module` so we are calling it like that `pd.Dateoffset()` and there `date` is the date entered by you when you calling the function

Comment: @Yaser then in the else part inside the function replace that date variable to `date=pd.to_datetime('01-12-20',dayfirst=True)`

Comment: Sorry I mean if we enter 01-03-18, 01-06-2018 and 01-09-2018 then it should become only 01-12-2017.

Comment: @Yaser then you can create a `if` condition inside else `block`

Comment: Can you please update the code or paste in comments?

Comment: @Yaser updated answer...kindly have a look ***:)***